# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openerp' in odoo v8

Tags: python, module, odoo-8

I'm using Odoo version 8. I want to create my first module but I had this problem that I haven't been able to solve:

```
/usr/bin/python3.8 /home/lenovo/odoo_work/mylibrary2/mylibrary2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lenovo/odoo_work/mylibrary2/mylibrary2.py", line 2, in <module>
    from openerp import models, fields, api
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openerp'
```

Process finished with exit code 1

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

Comment: have you installed the openerp module through pip or some other package manager?

Comment: honestly it is not me who install it, can you tell me how I can know it please!
and look at this:
~ $ service openerp restart
Failed to restart openerp.service: Unit openerp.service not found.

Comment: See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/588512/838556